# Make Git automatically remove trailing white space before committing

Tags: git, whitespace, githooks

I'm using Git with my team and would like to remove white space changes from my diffs, logs, merges, etc. I'm assuming that the easiest way to do this would be for Git to automatically remove trailing white space (and other white space errors) from all commits as they are applied.

I have tried to add the following to the `~/.gitconfig` file, but it doesn't do anything when I commit. Maybe it's designed for something different. What's the solution?

```
[core]
    whitespace = trailing-space,space-before-tab
[apply]
    whitespace = fix
```

I'm using Ruby in case anyone has any Ruby specific ideas. Automatic code formatting before committing would be the next step, but that's a hard problem and is not really causing a big problem.

Comment: If the core.whitespace directive doesn't fix your issues, you can also change the pre-commit hook (.git/hooks/pre-commit) to find and fix them for you. See [this](http://snipplr.com/view/8399/git-whitespace-fixes-for-windows-newlines/) post for a detailed description.

Comment: I got frustrated with similar whitespace errors and partial solutions, and wrote a flexible and fairly feature-complete utility which can fix **or** simply report whitespace errors that bedevil version control systems:  [Whitespace Total Fixer on Github](https://github.com/dlenski/wtf) (apologies if this is too self-promotional)

Comment: It seems like an independent tool that continually monitors the folder for changed files and modifies them would be easier.

Answer (score 124):

Those settings (`core.whitespace` and `apply.whitespace`) are not there to remove trailing whitespace but to:

- `core.whitespace`: detect them, and raise errors
- `apply.whitespace`: and strip them, but only during patch, not "always automatically"

I believe the **[`git hook pre-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit)** would do a better job for that (includes removing trailing whitespace)

---

Note that at any given time you can choose to not run  the `pre-commit` hook:

- temporarily: `git commit --no-verify .`
- permanently: `cd .git/hooks/ ; chmod -x pre-commit`

Warning: by default, a `pre-commit` script (like [this one](http://www.rpcurnow.force9.co.uk/git/tdl.git/hooks/pre-commit)), has *not* a "remove trailing" feature", but a "warning" feature like:

```
if (/\s$/) {
    bad_line("trailing whitespace", $_);
}
```

You could however **[build a better `pre-commit` hook](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119055419/http://newartisans.com:80/2009/02/building-a-better-pre-commit-hook-for-git/)**, especially when you consider that:

> Committing in Git with only some changes added to the staging area still results in an “atomic” revision that *may never have existed as a working copy and may not work*.

---

For instance, [oldman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792416/oldman) proposes [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22704385/6309) a [`pre-commit` hook](https://github.com/imoldman/config/blob/master/pre-commit.git.sh) which detects and remove whitespace.
Since that hook get the file name of each file, I would recommend to be careful for certain type of files: you don't want to remove trailing whitespace in `.md` (markdown) files!

---

Another approach, suggested by [hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-white-space-before-committing/592014?noredirect=1#comment123842676_592014):

> You can have two spaces at end of line in markdown and not have it as trailing whitespace by adding "`\`" before `\n`.

Then a content filter driver:

```
git config --global filter.space-removal-at-eol.clean 'sed -e "s/ \+$//"'
# register in .gitattributes 
*.md filter=space-removal-at-eol
```

Comment: Turns out git can be convinced to fix whitespace in your working copy via `apply.whitespace`, by tricking git into treating your working copy changes as a patch. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15398512/470844).

Comment: > "you don't want to remove trailing whitespace in .md (markdown) files" - Why is that? What is the purpose of trailing whitespace in markdown files? I noticed some `.editorconfig` files have a specific rule for that.

Comment: @friederbluemle depending on the type of markdown, a trailing double space indicate `<br>`: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/26#issuecomment-5825759

Comment: Setting `core.whitespace` to `trailing-space` with `git config` does not raise error when committing in `git` 2.5.0.

Comment: You can have two spaces at end of line in markdown and not have it as trailing whitespace by adding "\" before \n. Mind thought that not all tools that say they handle Markdown support all of Markdown so YMMV.

Comment: What I'm wondering a bit is why there ain't a filter for the configured whitespace rules in git. `git config --global filter.space-removal-at-eol.clean 'sed -e "s/ \+$//"'` is what I have with .gitattributes `*.md filter=space-removal-at-eol` as I was getting tired to fix all those little things after writing markdown. Now discovering the whitespace configuration more and more, wondering if this approach is useful/scales in general.

Comment: @hakre Nice use of a content filter driver there. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. That approach (content filter driver) means it is registered in the *code base* versioned by Git, but still need a `git config` to be active. It is more specific (limited to `md` files) then a whitespace config.

Comment: @VonC: Yes, and if git would ship with a built-in whitespace filter that is based on the project configuration, then (having the git version, granted) it would be available OOTB. I wonder if this is worth to bring forward.

Comment: @hakre You can mention it on https://public-inbox.org/git/, and see what counter-arguments are put forward.

Comment: Does `whitespace = fix` get applied during cherry-pick? (it seems to, but confirmation would be nice).

Answer (score 50):

You can trick Git into fixing the whitespace for you, by tricking Git into treating your changes as a patch. In contrast to the "pre-commit hook" solutions, these solutions add whitespace-fixing commands to Git.

Yes, these are hacks.

---

### Robust solutions

The following Git aliases are taken from 
[my `~/.gitconfig`](https://github.com/ntc2/conf/blob/79ceaa6f54402b4d3a2592bef845efa38c0102eb/dot.gitconfig).

By "robust" I mean that these aliases run without error, doing
the right thing, regardless of whether the tree or index are dirty. However, they don't work if an interactive `git rebase -i` is already in progress; see [my `~/.gitconfig`](https://github.com/ntc2/conf/blob/79ceaa6f54402b4d3a2592bef845efa38c0102eb/dot.gitconfig) for additional checks if you care about this corner case, where the `git add -e` trick described at the end should work.

If you want to run them directly in the shell, without creating a Git
alias, just copy and paste everything between the double quotes
(assuming your shell is Bash like).

#### Fix the index but not the tree

The following `fixws` Git alias fixes all whitespace errors in the index,
if any, but doesn't touch the tree:

```
# Logic:
#
# The 'git stash save' fails if the tree is clean (instead of
# creating an empty stash :P). So, we only 'stash' and 'pop' if
# the tree is dirty.
#
# The 'git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~' throws away the commit
# if it's empty, and adding '--keep-empty' prevents the whitespace
# from being fixed. So, we first check that the index is dirty.
#
# Also:
# - '(! git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD)' is true (zero) if
#   the index is dirty
# - '(! git diff-files --quiet .)' is true if the tree is dirty
#
# The 'rebase --whitespace=fix' trick is from here:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156679/470844
fixws = !"\
  if (! git diff-files --quiet .) && \
     (! git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD) ; then \
    git commit -m FIXWS_SAVE_INDEX && \
    git stash save FIXWS_SAVE_TREE && \
    git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~ && \
    git stash pop && \
    git reset --soft HEAD~ ; \
  elif (! git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD) ; then \
    git commit -m FIXWS_SAVE_INDEX && \
    git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~ && \
    git reset --soft HEAD~ ; \
  fi"
```

The idea is to run `git fixws` before `git commit` if you have
whitespace errors in the index.

#### Fix the index and the tree

The following `fixws-global-tree-and-index` Git alias fixes all whitespace
errors in the index and the tree, if any:

```
# The different cases are:
# - dirty tree and dirty index
# - dirty tree and clean index
# - clean tree and dirty index
#
# We have to consider separate cases because the 'git rebase
# --whitespace=fix' is not compatible with empty commits (adding
# '--keep-empty' makes Git not fix the whitespace :P).
fixws-global-tree-and-index = !"\
  if (! git diff-files --quiet .) && \
     (! git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD) ; then \
    git commit -m FIXWS_SAVE_INDEX && \
    git add -u :/ && \
    git commit -m FIXWS_SAVE_TREE && \
    git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~2 && \
    git reset HEAD~ && \
    git reset --soft HEAD~ ; \
  elif (! git diff-files --quiet .) ; then \
    git add -u :/ && \
    git commit -m FIXWS_SAVE_TREE && \
    git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~ && \
    git reset HEAD~ ; \
  elif (! git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD) ; then \
    git commit -m FIXWS_SAVE_INDEX && \
    git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~ && \
    git reset --soft HEAD~ ; \
  fi"
```

To also fix whitespace in unversioned files, do

```
git add --intent-to-add <unversioned files> && git fixws-global-tree-and-index
```

---

### Simple but not robust solutions

These versions are easier to copy and paste, but they don't do the
right thing if their side conditions are not met.

#### Fix the sub-tree rooted at the current directory (but resets the index if it's not empty)

Using `git add -e` to "edit" the patches with the identity editor `:`:

```
(export GIT_EDITOR=: && git -c apply.whitespace=fix add -ue .) && git checkout . && git reset
```

#### Fix and preserve the index (but fails if the tree is dirty or the index is empty)

```
git commit -m TEMP && git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~ && git reset --soft HEAD~
```

#### Fix the tree and the index (but resets the index if it's not empty)

```
git add -u :/ && git commit -m TEMP && git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~ && git reset HEAD~
```

---

#### Explanation of the `export GIT_EDITOR=: && git -c apply.whitespace=fix add -ue .` trick

Before I learned about the `git rebase --whitespace=fix` trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19156679/470844) I was using the more complicated `git add` trick everywhere.

If we did it manually:

1. Set `apply.whitespace` to `fix` (you only have to do this once):

   ```
   git config apply.whitespace fix
   ```

   This tells Git to fix whitespace in *patches*.
2. Convince Git to treat your changes as a *patch*:

   ```
   git add -up .
   ```

   Hit <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>to select all changes for each file.  You'll get a warning about Git fixing your whitespace errors.
   (`git -c color.ui=auto diff` at this point reveals that your non-indexed changes are exactly the whitespace errors).
3. Remove the whitespace errors from your working copy:

   ```
   git checkout .
   ```
4. Bring back your changes (if you aren't ready to commit them):

   ```
   git reset
   ```

The `GIT_EDITOR=:` means to use `:` as the editor, and as a command
`:` is the identity.

Comment: I just tested it in Windows: this works just fine in a DOS command prompt: `set VISUAL= && git add -ue . && git checkout .` Note the '`.`' used with `git add`: that is [because of git1.8.3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2190440/6309)

Comment: @VonC Won't that unset VISUAL permanently, which may e.g. cause a subsequent use of `git commit` to use the wrong editor? I wrap the `VISUAL=` part in a subshell in my unix version above to avoid this, but I don't know if DOS has subshells.

Comment: You are right, I suspect I would have to wrap that command line in a `.bat` file.

Comment: Thanks for the great hack!  FYI, if you have `core.editor` set then exporting `VISUAL` has no effect because the config setting takes precedence per `man git-var`. To override this you need to export `GIT_EDITOR=:` instead.

Comment: @NickFelt Thanks! I've updated the answer to use `GIT_EDITOR=:` instead as you suggest.

Comment: @ntc: I tried your first command (git fixws) and it does touch the working tree here, and if it tries to fix lines where the working tree has changes over the index, I am asked to merge... this is git 1.8.4.4.

Comment: FYI, I think the `fixws` script could use another tweak - it seems like some recent version of git (I'm on 2.4.3.573.g4eafbef) made it an error to `git stash pop` onto a dirty index.  This makes `git fixws` fail when attempting to run it with both a dirty index and tree.

To fix it, you can just move the `git stash pop` line above the `git reset --soft HEAD~` line. That seems like the correct sequence anyway.

Comment: Also, I tweaked my version of `fixws` to fail fast if you're already in an interactive rebase since otherwise it will die at the `git rebase --whitespace=fix` line and leave you in a weird state.  I borrowed from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3921928/1179226) and just added an extra case before the if:

`fixws = !"\
   if test -d $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/rebase-merge ; then \
     echo 'In rebase - cannot fixws' ; \
   elif (! git diff-files --quiet .) && \
      (! git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD) ; then \
...`

Comment: Thanks @NickFelt! I incorporated your first suggestion into the answer, and put your second suggestion in my actual config. I'm not going to add your second suggestion to the answer here though, since I don't think that corner case is worth the extra complication here.

Comment: fyi: I adapted this into a [pre-commit hook](https://iankelling.org/git/?p=ian-specific/config-files;a=blob;f=.git_template/hooks/pre-commit;hb=HEAD)

Comment: @ntc2: `fixws` does not work if no previous commits have been made. Is there an easy fix for handling that condition? The workaround of committing something and rebasing is not difficult, of course, but it would be nice to make `fixws` even more robust.

Answer (score 30):

I found a Git [pre-commit hook that removes trailing white space](http://snipplr.com/view/28523/git-precommit-hook-to-fix-trailing-whitespace/).

```
#!/bin/sh

if git-rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
   against=HEAD
else
   # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
   against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi
# Find files with trailing whitespace
for FILE in `exec git diff-index --check --cached $against -- | sed '/^[+-]/d' | sed -r 's/:[0-9]+:.*//' | uniq` ; do
   # Fix them!
   sed -i 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$FILE"
   git add "$FILE"
done
exit
```

Comment: The second `sed` invocation (`sed -r 's/:[0-9]+:.*//'`) could be substituted with `cut -f1 -d:`. This should work the same on both Linux and BSD based platforms.

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko: actually, using `cut` is not as safe as the second `sed`: cut will fail in the (highly unlikely) case of filenames that contain ":". You could use `awk 'NF>2{NF-=2}1'` to be safe

Comment: BTW, If you're on Windows (msysgit) and use `core.autocrlf=true`, you may want to add `dos2unix -D "$FILE"` inside the for loop, after sed. Otherwise, it will change all CRLFs to LFs by issuing only sed.

Comment: Doing `git add` inside a commit hook seems pretty evil to me. What if you are doing partial staging/committing of a file? You don't want the complete file to be committed behind your back, do you?

Answer (score 20):

On macOS (or, likely, any BSD), the sed command parameters have to be slightly different. Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if git-rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
   against=HEAD
else
   # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
   against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# Find files with trailing whitespace
for FILE in `exec git diff-index --check --cached $against -- | sed '/^[+-]/d' | sed -E 's/:[0-9]+:.*//' | uniq` ; do
    # Fix them!
    sed -i '' -E 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$FILE"
    git add "$FILE"
done
```

Save this file as `.git/hooks/pre-commit` -- or look for the one that's already there, and paste the bottom chunk somewhere inside it. And remember to `chmod a+x` it too.

Or for global use (via [Applying a git post-commit hook to all current and future repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293498)) you can put it in `$GIT_PREFIX/git-core/templates/hooks` (where GIT_PREFIX is /usr or /usr/local or /usr/share or /opt/local/share) and run `git init` inside your existing repos.

According to `git help init`:

> Running `git init` in an existing repository is safe. It will not overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for rerunning `git init` is to pick up newly added templates.

Comment: Isn't this hook modifying the working file and overwriting the index with the modified working file? If you were to 'git add -p' to construct your index, this commit hook would blow that away.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. Someone may have to rewrite this script to use  `git hash-object -w` and `git update-index` to (re)insert the munged file directly into the index. Someone very brave.

Answer (score 18):

## Using Git attributes, and filters setup with Git configuration

OK, this is a new tack on solving this problem… My approach is to not use any hooks, but rather use filters and Git attributes. This allows you to set up, on each machine you develop on, a set of filters that will strip extra trailing white space and extra blank lines at the end of files before committing them.

Then set up a .gitattributes file that says which types of files the filter should be applied to. The filters have two phases, `clean` which is applied when adding files to the index, and `smudge` which is applied when adding them to the working directory.

### Tell your Git to look for a global attributes file

First, tell your global configuration to use a global attributes file:

```
git config --global core.attributesfile ~/.gitattributes_global
```

### Create global filters

Now, create the filter:

```
git config --global filter.fix-eol-eof.clean fixup-eol-eof %f
git config --global filter.fix-eol-eof.smudge cat
git config --global filter.fix-eol-eof.required true
```

### Add the [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) scripting magic

Finally, put the `fixup-eol-eof` script somewhere on your path, and make it executable. The script uses sed to do some on the fly editing (remove spaces and blanks at the end of lines, and extraneous blank lines at the end of the file)

fixup-eol-eof should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's/[     ]*$//' -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}' $1
```

[My gist of this](https://gist.github.com/zbeekman/c3f2ef40ea176ba550fe)

### Tell Git which file types to apply your newly created filter to

Lastly, create or open file *~/.gitattributes_global* in your favorite text editor and add lines like:

```
pattern attr1 [attr2 [attr3 […]]]
```

So if we want to fix the white space issue, for all of our C source files we would add a line that looks like this:

```
*.c filter=fix-eol-eof
```

## Discussion of the filter

The filter has two phases. The clean phase which is applied when things are added to the index or checked in, and the smudge phase when Git puts stuff into your working directory.

Here, our smudge is just running the contents through the `cat` command which should leave them unchanged, with the exception of possibly adding a trailing newline character if there wasn’t one at the end of the file.

The clean command is the white space filtering which I cobbled together from notes at http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt. It seems that it must be put into a shell script. I couldn’t figure out how to inject the sed command, including the sanitation of the extraneous extra lines at the end of the file directly into the git-config file. (You *can* get rid of trailing blanks, however, without the need of a separate sed script. Just set the `filter.fix-eol-eof` to something like `sed 's/[ \t]*$//' %f` where the `\t` is an actual tab, by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.)

The `require = true` causes an error to be raised if something goes wrong, to keep you out of trouble.

Comment: Thanks @VonC! I also want to take this opportunity to point out that the git attributes can be configured in a per-repisitory basis in the `.git` folder rather than globally, which might make more sense.

Comment: `sed -e 's/[     ]*$//'` -- You can just use `\s` for both spaces and tabs, so `sed -e 's/\s*$//'` will do the job.

Answer (score 14):

I'd rather leave this task to your favorite editor.

Just set a command to remove trailing spaces when saving.

Comment: In vim you can do this with: autocmd BufWritePre *.cpp,*.c,*.h :%/\s\+$//e

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted the above comment before testing it. There is a missing "s" after the percent sign, and it will move the cursor around if whitespace is found, and it will remove the last search pattern. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces for better alternatives.

Comment: In emacs it's M-x delete-trailing-whitespace.

Comment: Better still, for emacs, set a hook to delete trailing whitespace before saving by adding `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)` to your `.emacs` file. [Emacs whitespace tricks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace)

Comment: I use (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'whitespace-cleanup) which also converts tabs to spaces.

Comment: This is by far the safest and most robust solution. I have wasted hours fixing unexpected problems caused by seemingly innocent pre-commit hooks.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote this pre-commit hook, which only removes the trailing white space from the lines which you've changed/added, since the previous suggestions tend to create unreadable commits if the target files have too much trailing white space.

```
#!/bin/sh

if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
   against=HEAD
else
   # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
   against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

IFS='
'

files=$(git diff-index --check --cached $against -- | sed '/^[+-]/d' | perl -pe 's/:[0-9]+:.*//' | uniq)
for file in $files ; do
    diff=$(git diff --cached $file)
    if test "$(git config diff.noprefix)" = "true"; then
        prefix=0
    else
        prefix=1
    fi
    echo "$diff" | patch -R -p$prefix
    diff=$(echo "$diff" | perl -pe 's/[ \t]+$// if m{^\+}')
    out=$(echo "$diff" | patch -p$prefix -f -s -t -o -)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$diff" | patch -p$prefix -f -t -s
    fi
    git add $file
done
```

Comment: Interesting. +1. See [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/6309) for computing the empty tree.

Comment: Good idea, this is exactly what I would want. However, be careful when using this! For me on OSX and git version 2.3.5 it blows away any add but uncommitted changes i have staged. I would still be interested in a working solution for this though.

Answer (score 9):

Please try [my **pre-commit** hooks](https://github.com/imoldman/config/blob/master/pre-commit.git.sh). It can auto detect trailing white space and ***remove it***.

It can work under [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) (Windows), Mac OS X and Linux!

---

Snapshot:

```
$ git commit -am "test"
auto remove trailing whitespace in foobar/main.m!
auto remove trailing whitespace in foobar/AppDelegate.m!
[master 80c11fe] test
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Interesting. +1. I have referenced your hook in [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/592014/6309)

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your affirmation! To the '.md', I only found `git commit -no-verify`, any sugesstions?

Comment: I would rather make the hook able to detect `.md` file and not remove the whitespaces, rather than asking the end user to add a `--no-verify` option on the `git commit`.

Comment: Fails if committing a file/directory that starts with a `+` or `-`

Answer (score 7):

Here is an Ubuntu and Mac OS X compatible version:

```
#!/bin/sh
#

# A Git hook script to find and fix trailing white space
# in your commits. Bypass it with the --no-verify option
# to git-commit
#

if git-rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  against=HEAD
else
  # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
  against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi
# Find files with trailing whitespace
for FILE in `exec git diff-index --check --cached $against -- | sed '/^[+-]/d' | (sed -r 's/:[0-9]+:.*//' > /dev/null 2>&1 || sed -E 's/:[0-9]+:.*//') | uniq` ; do
  # Fix them!
  (sed -i 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$FILE" > /dev/null 2>&1 || sed -i '' -E 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$FILE")
  git add "$FILE"
done

# Now we can commit
exit
```

Comment: Looks like the only difference between yours and mine is that you check that sed will actually replace something before rewriting the file... I'm not sure that matters since git doesn't commit changes that don't actually change anything. I suppose it's marginally safer, but also marginally slower, and I prefer the clarity of not repeating the regexes twice on one line. De gustibus non disputandum est!

Comment: no the difference is that the version is using the ubuntu syntax first and (if that fails) afterwards the osx one.

Comment: i editted sdepold's post, it should be able to also allow whitespaces in filenames now.

Comment: I think we could use this `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD` to get init commit

Answer (score 6):

I was thinking about this today. This is all I ended up doing for a Java project:

```
egrep -rl ' $' --include *.java *  | xargs sed -i 's/\s\+$//g'
```

Answer (score 4):

For [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) users.

Set the following properly in your *Setting-User* configuration.

```
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
```

Comment: Is it a way to set this by file type? I have `*.md` (markdown) files that rely on "  " (trailing double-spaces) for marking a simple `<br />`, and that setting seem to apply to *all* files, including the ones I *don't* want to remove the trailing spaces.

Comment: @VonC There is hierarchy on how configuration is applied more details here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983328/how-to-turn-removing-whitespaces-off-for-some-files-in-sublime-text-2 hope it helps

Comment: This isn't related to git

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't remove white space **automatically** before a commit, but it is pretty easy to effect. I put the following [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) script in a file named git-wsf (Git white space fix) in a directory in $PATH, so I can:

```
git wsf | sh
```

And it removes all white space *only* from lines of files that Git reports as a diff.

```
#! /bin/sh
git diff --check | perl -x $0
exit

#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %stuff;
while (<>) {
    if (/trailing whitespace./) {
        my ($file,$line) = split(/:/);
        push @{$stuff{$file}},$line;
    }
}

while (my ($file, $line) = each %stuff) {
    printf "ex %s <<EOT\n", $file;
    for (@$line) {
        printf '%ds/ *$//'."\n", $_;
    }
    print "wq\nEOT\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop for files uses the `$IFS` shell variable.
In the given script, filenames with a character in them that also is in the $IFS-variable will be seen as two different files in the `for` loop.

This script fixes it: multiline-mode modifier as given in the [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) manual doesn't seem to work by default on my Ubuntu box, so I sought for a different implementation and found this with an iterating label, essentially it will only start substitution on the last line of the file if I've understood it correctly.

```
#!/bin/sh
#

# A Git hook script to find and fix trailing white space
# in your commits. Bypass it with the --no-verify option
# to git-commit
#

if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    against=HEAD
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

SAVEIFS="$IFS"
# only use new-line character as separator, introduces EOL-bug?
IFS='
'
# Find files with trailing white space
for FILE in $(
    git diff-index --check --cached $against -- \
    | sed '/^[+-]/d' \
    | ( sed -r 's/:[0-9]+:.*//' || sed -E 's/:[0-9]+:.*//' ) \
    | uniq \
)
do
# replace whitespace-characters with nothing
# if first execution of sed-command fails, try second one (Mac OS X version)
    (
        sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\+$//' "$FILE" > /dev/null 2>&1 \
        || \
        sed -i '' -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\+$//' "$FILE" \
    ) \
    && \
# (re-)add files that have been altered to Git commit-tree
#   when change was a [:space:]-character @EOL|EOF git-history becomes weird...
    git add "$FILE"
done
# restore $IFS
IFS="$SAVEIFS"

# Exit script with the exit-code of git's check for white space characters
exec git diff-index --check --cached $against --
```

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) sed-substitution pattern: *[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n/7697604#7697604)*

Comment: The footnote does not seem to be referenced. What is the intent?

Answer (score 0):

### Python Script for the same result.

```
import subprocess                                                                 
                                                                              
def get_trailing_lines():                                                         
                                                                              
    result = subprocess.run([                                                     
                            'git',                                            
                            'diff',                                           
                            '--check'                                         
                        ], capture_output=True)                               
                                                                              
    return result.stdout.decode().split('\n')                                     
                                                                              
                                                                              
def modify_line(file_path, l_num):                                                
                                                                              
    f_lines = open(file_path).readlines()                                         
    f_lines[l_num] = f_lines[l_num].rstrip()+'\n'\                                
                     if '\n' in f_lines[l_num] else f_lines[l_num].rstrip()    
                                                                              
    with open(file_path, "w") as w_fp:                                            
        w_fp.writelines(f_lines)                                                  
                                                                              
                                                                              
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                        
                                                                              
    l = get_trailing_lines()                                                      
    for m, d in zip(l[::2], l[1::2]):                                             
        f_path, l_no, *_ = m.split(":")                                           
        modify_line(f_path, int(l_no)-1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This probably won't directly solve your problem, but you might want to set those via [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) in your actual project space, which edits file *./.git/config* as opposed to file *~/.gitconfig*. It is nice to keep the settings consistent among all project members.

```
git config core.whitespace "trailing-space,space-before-tab"
git config apply.whitespace "trailing-space,space-before-tab"
```

Comment: afaik, settings inside .git are *not* shared with anyone else; they're specific to your local repo

Answer (score -2):

Open the file in Vim. To replace tabs with white spaces, type the following on the Vim command line:

```
:%s#\t#    #gc
```

To get rid of other trailing white spaces

```
:%s#\s##gc
```

This pretty much did it for me. It's tedious if you have a lot of files to edit. But I found it easier than pre-commit hooks and working with multiple text editors.

Comment: If it gets to tedious - and if you have a backup of what you are about to edit - then I often just use sed to change tabs to spaces: `sed -i 's|\t|    |g'  filenames` (spaces in the replace position).  Note that you can use find to get your filenames.  If you have not thought of how to get that backup, I usually just commit everything and then 'undo' the commit with a soft reset back to where I am; sometimes I add everything to the tree but don't commit, and sometimes I use the stash/apply (not pop!).  If I feel anxious, I rsync my entire tree to a safe location before meddling...

Answer (score -2):

To delete trailing white space at the end of lines in a file portably, use `ed`:

```
test -s file &&
   printf '%s\n' H ',g/[[:space:]]*$/s///' 'wq' | ed -s file
```