# git - trim whitespace

Tags: git, whitespace, code-cleanup, removing-whitespace

I've accidentally put some whitespace in [my initial commit](http://github.com/josh-brown/euler-python/commit/5eed0c8874141b87deae35de57589cd38e03dfaa) - it shows up red in `git diff --color`. What's the best way to get rid of the existing whitespace and how can I avoid this happening again?

I am not necessarily looking for a built-in **git** command. Any external program available for free on Ubuntu would also be welcome.

Comment: awesome I didn't know git had this feature.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/591923/470844).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make git automatically remove trailing whitespace before committing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To trim trailing whitespace on all files in the current directory, use:

```
sed -i 's/[[:space:]]*$//' *
```

To warn about future whitespace errors (both **trailing spaces** and **spaces before tabs**), and to fix whitespace errors in patches, add the following code to your `gitconfig` file:

```
[core]
    whitespace = trailing-space,space-before-tab
[apply]
    whitespace = fix
```

Comment: this is good for protecting against whitespace commits but the OP asked about removing whitespace they's already commited

Comment: @stevejpurves: The top line explains how to remove trailing whitespace using *sed*. As far as I know, there is no git command that does the same thing.

Answer (score 15):

`core.whitespace` instructs git to flag certain whitespace problems:

- `trailing-space` warns about whitespace at the end of a line or at the end of a file
- `space-before-tab` warns when there is a space before a tab used for indentation

`apply.whitespace` is used when applying a patch. It checks for whitespace errors (the ones listed above, in `core.whitespace`) and applies the patch after attempting to fix them (i.e., remove them).

These options go in `~/.gitconfig` -- that is, a `.gitconfig` file at the root of your user's home directory (typically `/home/user/.gitconfig` on Linux, `/Users/user/.gitconfig` on Mac OS X, and I don't know where on Windows but I suppose somewhere in `C:\Documents and Settings\user`).

Comment: That explains the whitespace settings (+1 for that) but doesn't answer the question "How do I get rid of existing whitespace?". I've updated the original post for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

See this thread [git remove trailing whitespace in new files before commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151940/git-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-new-files-before-commit) on using `git rebase` to strip whitespace from files that you've already committed.

Comment: TL;DR: To fix-up the last commit in terms of whitespace, use 
    `git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~`

Answer (score 2):

And to trim the white spaces from all files recursively from all sub directories this can be used.

```
find ./* -type f -exec sed -i 's/[[:space:]]*$//' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
git rebase --whitespace=fix --root
```

This was already linked to in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299760/2716218 but worth putting as it's own clean answer.