# Remove trailing whitespace in modified lines

Tags: git, bash, removing-whitespace

I want to remove trailing whitespace from my modifications to files.

However, this is different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151940/git-remove-trailing-whitespace-in-new-files-before-commit) because I want to do it whenever, without committing.

For example,

1. Remove trailing whitespace.
2. `git diff`
3. Review code with another programmer.
4. `git commit`

But I don't want to remove trailing whitespace from lines I didn't modify, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372822/git-trim-whitespace) won't work for me either.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15398512/1256452 (note: I have not tried this myself, but it looks like exactly what you want).

Comment: Some editors can do it upon Save. Eclipse does it happily and has a setting of "only in changed lines". If not - bash script is your choice. Git diff will display the changed lines and sed will remove the trailing whitespace.