# Git does not warn about badly written whitespace

Tags: git, whitespace

I've set config of git so that 'git config --list' gives following:

```
core.editor=vim
core.whitespace=trailing-space,space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
```

But when I want to commit a file whit trailing space or other whitespace problem, it never complains. Don't know what I can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For it to warn you during commit, I believe you have to write a `pre-commit` hook which will check for the appropriate whitespace and warn you.

Related question regarding removing whitespace: [Make git automatically remove trailing whitespace before committing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing/3516525#3516525)

Comment: Well, last time I had installed git on my other machine, I did not have to write any hook. On the other hand, I don't want it to happen automatically, I just want to be warned.