# How to turn removing whitespaces off for some files in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have an option `trim_trailing_white_space_on_save` turned on. And for some files I should prevent removing trailing white spaces, because they are important.

How to remove this behaviour for some files, e.g. *.dat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you already tried to create a configuration file for that specific extension and put trim_trailing_white_space_on_save = false ?

> ## Settings Files
>
> Settings files are consulted in this order:
>
> 1. Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings
> 2. Packages/Default/Preferences (< platform >).sublime-settings
> 3. Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
> 4. < Project Settings >
> 5. Packages/< syntax >/< syntax >.sublime-settings
> 6. Packages/User/.sublime-settings
> 7. < Buffer Specific Settings >
>
> In general, you should place your settings in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings.
>
> If you want to specify settings for a certain file type, for example, Python, you should place them in Packages/User/Python.sublime-settings.

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime 3, just open any file with the extension you'd like to have specific settings for, and go to `Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific`.

In my case I did it for Markdown (.md) and Sublime created a `Markdown.sublime-settings` file in which I added the following:

```
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": false,
```

In your case, for a .dat file, Sublime will create a `Plain text.sulbime-settings file` in which you can add the exact same setting.