# use git apply --whitespace=fix from command line to manually fix normal text files

Tags: git, removing-whitespace

I have a number of text files and from time to time I start up a tool that removes the trailing white space. Is it possible to use `git apply --whitespace=fix` for that purpose (and get rid of the other tool I was using)?

I tried something like `git apply --whitespace=fix testfile.txt` but that did **not** work, 
I guess it only works on patch files, but I want to use it with any kind of text files.

I do not want to run the command on every check-out or commit (there are some answers doing that), I just want to run it manually from time to time and if I like the output, I will commit it, separately from changes to the content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing.

Comment: @Jayan yes, I am aware of that question, but I do not want to automatically remove whitespace on every commit, I want to use it more like a standalone tool

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try the following command line to ignore whitespace.

```
git apply --ignore-whitespace patch.diff
```

Generally, I used this to apply a patch.