# Git revert all changes that are ignored by git diff -w

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

When I do

```
git diff -w file_name
```

I see only added lines but when I remove `-w` I see lots of removed and re-added lines too.

I want to change the file so that I will show only the changes that are not ignored by `-w` option.

Is there a command for that?

Comment: Maybe using a script similar to the pre-commit hook I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/592014/6309?

Comment: @VonC : I would be very grateful if you could please that script for us.

Comment: @Abhishek do you mean like this one? https://github.com/imoldman/config/blob/master/pre-commit.git.sh

Comment: Because my file is from a shared repository, I want to minimize the changes I commit/push to it.  I want a script which reverts a change (at the granularity of individual lines) if and only if it is a mere-line-ending change. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

jupp0r was on the right track. First, `cd` to the root of your repository. Then:

```
git commit -a -m 'Backup commit.'
git branch pre-patch
git reset --hard HEAD~
git diff --patch -w HEAD pre-patch > patch.diff
git apply patch.diff
```

I'm not sure whether this will work for binary changes. If not, you can commit those separately beforehand. If this process fails, your code is in the `pre-patch` branch.

What this does:

- Creates a commit and a branch to store the full changes. This also serves as a backup.
- Goes back a step, to before those changes were made.
- Gets the "diff -w" from the old code to the new code, formatted as a patch.
- Applies the patch.

Note: If you've already committed the change and want to modify it, just omit the first step.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
git diff --no-color > stage.diff && git apply -R stage.diff && git apply --whitespace=fix stage.diff && rm -f stage.diff
```

If you haven't committed any changes yet.