# ^M being inserted into all my code by git

Tags: git, terminal, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm using Bitbucket and I don't know if that is important.

Why is `^M` being inserted after every line of my source code after merge conflicts. I'm not using Source Tree, just regular git through terminal.

Comment: ^M is the same as CR (Carriage return). On Windows, every line ends with CR+LF (unless you set up your editor differently). On Linux, CR has no special meaning and is displayed as ^M.

This question is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing

You are getting -1 for swearing in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git-diff to ignore ^M](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/git-diff-to-ignore-m)

Comment: It blows my mind that we're *still* mucking about with CRLF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text editor is showing this escape character if your file contains a mixture of unix and windows style line endings. This is most probably caused by how your text editor and git are set up.

Personally, I always ensure that I checkout from git using unix line endings (also on Windows) and submitting unix line endings, too. In the .gitattributes files you can e.g. specify:

```
* text eol=lf
```

Normally, good text editors respect the line ending they find and don't try to convert a file. But you might check the configuration of your text editor.

There is no automated solution for the file having a mixture of both kinds of line endings (^M). You have to go through the file and remove those characters.