# Azure dev ops pipeline failed: contains the character '*'. Remove the '*' and try again

Tags: azure-devops

I am publishing artifact and some supporting files for release phase.

Error I am getting:

```
Fail to upload '/home/vsts/work/1/a/app.yaml' due to 'TF10123: The
path '**/app.yaml' contains the character '*'. Remove the '*' and try
again.'.
```

There is no * in app.yaml file, please tell me what to do to fix this.

Let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Hi @Indrajeet Gour How was it going with this case, Did you work it out? if not, could share a screenshot of your publish artifact task?

Answer (score 0):

Check your file if it contains any whitespace characters (invisible ones, so use a HEX format display....), remove those characters and commit it again.

Comment: I tried removing the extra charaters from the all the files use dos2unix before publish it but it did not work out. Do you have any other idea for this.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing)...